# Jcombobox algorithm

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox

```
    jComboBox1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jComboBox1ActionPerformed(evt);

          if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().equals(" ")) 
            {
                rlsum = addElement(sumthing );
            }
         if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().equals("S")) 
            {
                rlsum = addElement(sumthing/64 );
            } 
         if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().equals("Z")) 
            {
                rlsum = addElement(sumthing/220 );
            } 
       }

        private Object addElement(double i) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    });
```

I was wondering how would I get the variable sumthing to be read without being thrown every time... I added the actionlisteners with the matching labels to my Jcombo box but every time I selected a label it refers to the thrown code..

Comment: your addElement method is throwing RuntimeException. dont call it until you implement it.

Comment: can you give me an example of how it would look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem lies in below code. You are throwing `UnsupportedException` during `addElement` operation

```
private Object addElement(double i) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
```

First implement your addElement with logic relevant to your application need.

replace `addElement()` with below code , for not to throw Exception

```
 private Object addElement(double i) {

            //put your business logic, add relevant exception handling for your requirement
            }
```